# Updating gmaps4rails 'clusters' when hiding or showing visible markers

Tags: gmaps4rails, visible, marker, markerclusterer

This javascript code hides all the markers on a google map which I initially populated using the gmaps4rails gem in a Rails 3.2 app.

```
var markers=Gmaps.map.markers
for(i=0;i<markers.length;i++){markers[i].serviceObject.setVisible(false); }
```

The issue I have is that the "clusters" still show the same counters before and after the above code is ran. I've searched around a bit and haven't figured out the write line(s) to add to update the clusters.

P.S. I'm *pretty* sure that "cluster" is the correct name for what I'm talking about. What I'm referring to are the counters that the map shows when you are zoomed out to a view where there isn't enough room to distinguish between individual markers and the map shows a colored, circularish icon with a count of the number of map markers in that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update your map with a different set of markers, we'll call them `differentMarkers` you can call

```
var differentMarkers = ...
Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(differentMarkers);
```

and the clusters will update.

If you want to add markers to the existing set use

```
var additionalMarkers = ...
Gmaps.map.addMarkers(additionalMarkers);
```

I haven't found a method to remove markers but you could call the `replaceMarkers` with an array that has the markers removed.

Not sure if this is the way it is meant to be done but seems to work.

---

Adding and replacing markers this way is also explained in the wiki for gmaps4rails. https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies